# confusing result from pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, range, cut

I need to create ranges from sequential values which has minimum value 0 and maximum value 1990161.

I was thinking to create 5 ranges with equal length so applied "pd.cut" and got this result.

```
pd.cut(df['v'], 5)
----------------------------------------------
[(-1990.161, 398032.2], (796064.4, 1194096.6], (398032.2, 796064.4], (1194096.6, 1592128.8], (1592128.8, 1990161.0]]
Categories (5, interval[float64]): [(-1990.161, 398032.2] < (398032.2, 796064.4] < (796064.4, 1194096.6] < (1194096.6, 1592128.8] < (1592128.8, 1990161.0]]
```

what i expected was "pd.cut" make range from actual values, so the lowest range should've started 0. But it was -1990.161.

I've searched some codes and tried this.

```
lower, higher = df['v'].min(), df['v'].max()
n_bins= 5
edges = range(lower, higher+5, int(round((higher - lower)/n_bins,0)))
lbs = ['(%d, %d]'%(edges[i], edges[i+1]) for i in range(len(edges)-1)]
pd.cut(df['v'], bins=n_bins, labels=lbs, include_lowest=True)
----------------------------------------------
Categories (5, object): [(0, 398032] < (398032, 796064] < (796064, 1194096] < (1194096, 1592128] < (1592128, 1990160]]
```

I think there were two problems.. 
first, that labels don't seem correct... those labels (0,398032] and  (1592128, 1990160], which min(0) and max(1990161) belong to, says it doesn't include 0, 1990161 but those values are included.

second, that codes above just added labels not adjust boundary of range. That means that results has the same range as the first code still.

The reason why i used "pd.cut" was it automatically calculate the same length from range of values.

Is there any other way to adjust the boundary of range except applying bins like [0, 3000, 5000 ...] by creating list?

Maybe I misunderstood the logic or result of "pd.cut", so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually we should subtract and add the bins to `min` and `max`

```
binsize=df.v.ptp()//5
pd.cut(df['v'], bins=range(df.v.min()-binsize//5,df.v.max()+binsize,binsize), include_lowest=True)
```